# Перезапуск Активити

Tags: android

Есть  две активити - 1 и 2. С первого  перехожу  на  второе.
Мне  нужно, чтобы при  нажатии  на  кнопку  back (назад)  перезапустилось  активити 1, но  не с  сохраненного  состояния, а  с  вызова  метода  onCreate.  То  есть  заново  создать  активити 1.

Как  такое  сотворить?

Заранее  благодарю.

Comment: А не проще код с onCreate перенести в onStart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ловите событие onBackPressed и запускайте активити из него.

```
Intent i = new Intent( this , this.getClass() );    
finish();    
this.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Согласен. Но  тогда  придется  в  первой активити  так же  обрабатывать onBackPressed. Хотя  в принципе это не критично))

Comment: А если метод finish() использовать  при  переходе  на  вторую активность?

Answer (score 3):

Вы хотите странного. :) Скорее всего, вам не нужно перезапускать активити 1. Кроме того, вы сводите на нет закешированное состояние. Попробуйте перенести код, который должен выполняться при каждом открытии активити в метод `onStart`.

Comment: Ну не  совсем  странного. В onCreate  я  подключаю  кастомную  вьюху, а  она  запускает  поток,  в  которой  происходит работа  с  переменными. Тут-то  как  раз  и  не  нужно  сохраненное  состояние (кэш). Но  все  равно  спасибо

Comment: @alexmx, а вы не можете создавать вьюху в `onCreate`, а запускать поток в `onStart` (и при необходимости в `onPause` его останавливать)? Вероятно, раз поток запускается из вьюхи, то он как-то обновляет UI, и соответственно, должен запускаться и останавливаться вместе с UI.